# How would I show if $N_1,\ldots, N_k$ are parallelizable manifolds, then so is $N_1\times \cdots \times N_k$?

Tags: manifolds

A smooth $n$-manifold $N$ is called parallelizable if it admits $n$ smooth vector fields $Y_1;\ :\ :\ :\ ;\ Y_n$ that are linearly independent at every point $p$ in $M$.

How would I show if if $N_1, \ldots, N_k$ are parallelizable manifolds, then so is $N_1\times\cdots\times N_k$?

Comment: Use that $T(N_1 \times \cdots \times N_k) = TN_1 \times \cdots \times TN_k$. Where do you see a problem?

Comment: Do it for two factors and use induction, to keep things minimally annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Following the comments:

- It suffices to prove the statement for $k=2$; induction does the rest.
- Since $T(N_1\times N_2) = TN_1 \times TN_2$, the union of  parallelizations of $TN_1$ and $TN_2$ is a  parallelization of  $T(N_1)\times N_2)$.